# Understanding the folder structure and files needed for using Bootstrap and Font-awesome

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a nodejs app, which include one folder in the root directory, whose layer is as follow:

```
/public
    /css
        /bootstrap.min.css
        /font-awesome.min.css
        /luqa.css
    /fonts
        /fontawesome-webfont.eot
        /fontawesome-webfont.svg
        /fontawesome-webfont.ttf
        /fontawesome-webfont.woff
        /fontawesome-webfont.woff2
        /fontawesome-webfont.otf
    /js
        /jquery-2.1.4.min.js
    some other picture file
```

I am a really newbie in this field. At first, I think this is about bootstrap, so I went to search about bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ But after I download its code, I found only `bootstrap.min.css` is the same. Others are all different.

I knew `luqa.css` is one self made css, to store some format used in html.

Then I searched font-awesome and downloaded it,
http://fontawesome.io/
 I found the files in `fonts` folder are all the same as well as `font-awesome.min.css` in the /css, but `font-awesome.css` is gone. Finally, I also tried the file in the /js folder, I download jquery file and there is only one file jquery-2.1.4.min.js to be same.

I am a really newbie in this field. I really want to know why they mix three kind of thing together, and files of these three part can be mixed together. You can delete the other part, what if you may want invoke those  deleted file? What's the relationship among those three parts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **bootstrap.min.css** is the style information for all the bootstrap components, it makes stuff look pretty and be responsive (change size and orientation to suit the viewing screen size)
- **font-awesome.min.css** is the style information for all the fontawesome icons, this tells the browser what font files to use for each icon and their default appearance
- **/fonts** all of these are the actual font files (images and the like) that make up the icons font-awesome uses, without these, font-awesome.min.css is useless. font-awesome.min.css imports these itself, no need to link to them in your html, but make sure the folder structure is as you have it or it'll break.
- **jquery-2.1.4.min.js** jQuery library, makes writing javascript simpler/quicker
- **bootstrap.min.js** You didnt list it here, but you should also have this file in the /js folder. This is what actually adds bootstrap functionality (tooltips, popovers, carousels, tabs, and the like).

.

Final folder tree:

```
/public
    /css
        /bootstrap.min.css
        /font-awesome.min.css
        /luqa.css
    /fonts
        /fontawesome-webfont.eot
        /fontawesome-webfont.svg
        /fontawesome-webfont.ttf
        /fontawesome-webfont.woff
        /fontawesome-webfont.woff2
        /fontawesome-webfont.otf
    /js
        /jquery-2.1.4.min.js
        /bootstrap.min.js
    /index.html
```

Given the above folder structure, to use everything in index.html, you would have something like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/luqa.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <title>Some Title</title>
</head>
```

#### Some notes:

- Bootstrap depends on jQuery, you MUST load jQuery first
- Always load your custom CSS last so your styles will override those defined in the libraries you use.
- Dont leave out the 3 meta tags in the head, they MUST be present and at the top of the head or bootstrap components will not appear correctly on mobile devices.

Comment: Have you tried to reverse loading jquery and bootstrap? Because my app load bootstrap first but works well. And about bootstrap.min.js http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ says it is _Latest compiled and minified JavaScript_. My file doesn't include it but works well. So, is it not necessary to include it? Or just it doesn't influence as long as we don't use its function? My html, in fact, is ejs. Dose that influence?

Comment: **bootstrap.min.js** must be loaded after **jquery-2.1.4.min.js** because **bootstrap.min.js** depends on jquery. The one you are loading first is **bootstrap.min.css**. The order of loading `js` vs `css` is not hugely important in your case, though there is research to show loading CSS after your JS can be beneficial, hence it's the order I use.  Yes you definitely need **bootstrap.min.js**. You can get the styling with just the CSS file but you are going to be missing quite a lot of functionality. Whether or not you *need* that missing functionality, only you can say.